# How to encapsulate redis?

Tags: redis

I am using redis in telegram bots and now I want to deploy few bots on one cloud server. If it possible to encapsulate data from redis for each project to prevent mistakes?

My directory structure:

```
/webapps/
├── bot1                <= virtualenv for the application Hello
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── gunicorn            <= Hello app's gunicorn
│   │   ├── gunicorn_start      <= Hello app's gunicorn start script
│   │   └── python
│   ├── hello                   <= Hello app's bot project directory
│   │   └── hello
│   │       ├── settings.py     <= hello.settings
│   │       └── wsgi.py         <= hello.wsgi
│   ├── logs                    <= Hello app's logs will be saved here
│   ├── media
│   ├── run                     <= Gunicorn's socket file will be placed here
│   └── static
└── bot2              <= analogous virtualenv for the application Goodbye
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── gunicorn
    │   ├── gunicorn_start
    │   └── python
    ├── goodbye
    │   └── goodbye
    │       ├── settings.py
    │       └── wsgi.py
    ├── logs
    ├── media
    ├── run
    └── static
```

Comment: Thiis has little to do with encapsulation, devops, design patterns or folders. You're probably asking how to *isolate* the data used by each bot, not how to encapsulate Redis. Encapsulation would make sense if you wanted to create a Redis client library that exposed a simplified API on top of Redis' own API.

Comment: Multitenancy comes close to what you want. If you search for `Redis multitenancy` you'll see that only Redis Enterprise supports this out of the box, with a separate database per tenant. Other options are using a tenant-specific prefix either for the containers (works only if you have a few tenants/bots) or keys